# Joint pdf / limit of integration

Tags: probability

The pdf of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is as follows
  $f(x,y)=c(x^2+y)$ for $0<y<1-x^2$ and $0$ otherwise.

I have a problems finding the limits of integration for $x$. In the solution I found on the net they integrate from (-1 to 1). Is it bc every other value would make

0 < y < (some negative number) which cant be a true statement?

Many thanks for your answer

Comment: When you are provided with the joint pdf, you must have the joint support at hand. What is it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'for 0'?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, That is all info that is provided, i corrected an error in my post the pdf is c(x^2+y)

Comment: @MeetaJo sorry a part of my question was deleted, idk why I now typed in the missing part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support is $0\lt y\lt 1-x^2$, so $0<1-x^2$ and thus $x^2<1$.   Hence $-1< x<1$ is the maximum range over which you may integrate with respect to $x$.

For instance, to evaluate $c$, use $1=\iint_{\Bbb R^2} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathsf d (x,y)$, so

$$1 =\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{1-x^2} c~(x^2+y)~\mathsf dy~\mathsf d x$$